# Bluetooth mouse sleeps after a few seconds idle when there is no other mouse connected

Tags: linux, mouse, bluetooth

I bought a Microsoft 3600 bluetooth mouse and never managed to get it working properly on Linux, but it works fine in other operating systems.

If I stop moving the mouse for a few seconds (like 3 or 4 seconds) it "sleeps", and when I move it again the pointer won't move for the next few seconds. This makes this device completely unusable.

I already searched a lot about that and found lots of answers telling to change the timeout at the `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` (I didn't had that file by default tho) or create a udev rule. I already made they both and the problem persists.

Looking at journalctl, I get those messages when the mouse sleeps and I attempt to move it:

```
jul 03 19:41:46 nathan kernel: usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 24 using xhci_hcd
jul 03 19:41:46 nathan kernel: usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
jul 03 19:41:47 nathan kernel: usb 1-6: Device not responding to setup address.
jul 03 19:41:47 nathan kernel: usb 1-6: device not accepting address 24, error -71
jul 03 19:41:47 nathan kernel: usb usb1-port6: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I also noticed a weird behavior: If I keep my USB gaming mouse plugged in the USB, the Bluetooth mouse does not sleeps and works fine. But if I remove the USB mouse the problem starts occurring again in the bluetooth mouse.

I'm currently running on Manjaro with linux 5.7.0, but the same problem used to occur in OpenSuse too, with every single kernel version I tested (5.4.x, 5.5.x and 5.6.x).,

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's been about 3 years since I bought this mouse, TODAY I managed to fix it. It was about the USB device auto suspending for some reason

1. Do `# lsusb -vt` to get your USB device ID:

   ```
   λ ~> sudo lsusb -vt
   /:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
   ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
   /:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
   ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
   |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
       ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
   |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
       ID 0cf3:e500 Qualcomm Atheros Communications
   ```
2. Create a `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules` file if you don't have it already
3. Append to the end of this file: (replace the `idVendor` and `idProduct` with yours, see the example above)

   ```
   ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0cf3", 
   ATTR{idProduct}=="e500", ATTR{power/autosuspend}="-1"
   ```
4. Reboot

Today is a great day btw

Comment: Fixed the issue for me on a Logitech MX Master 2S on Kubuntu 22.04! I found it quite confusing reading where I was supposed to put my IDs as I thought that `idVendor` was supposed to be replaced, but it's the text next to it.

Comment: This also works on Ubunto 22.04, and a Logitech g603. But as said before keep in mind it's not the actual {idProduct} and {idVendor} you need to replace but the number after the equal sign

Comment: I've set them for all three devices in the branch containing `btusb`.

Comment: this worked for me on an ubuntu 22.04.2, with an MX Master 2S and a TP-Link usb bluetooth adapter. Curious, how would one do it if the bluetooth adapter is integrated and there is no USB involved?

Comment: @dimisjim that was actually my case, and I think the case of most of the people viewing this topic. I am pretty sure that the motherboards connects the integrated bluetooth devices to the USB bus, so it's basically a USB device anyway